# Definition of pull-back in gauge transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, physics, gauge-theory

In an online lecture given by a famous physicist Youshi Wu, he says:

> Consider a map $g:\quad M\rightarrow G:x\rightarrow g(x)\in G$ ($G$ is a Lie Group, $M$ can be physical space or spacetime), we have the pull-back $$\text{Tr}\left\{[g^{-1}(x)dg(x)]^{k}\right\}$$

I am not clear why the pull-back appear like this.

Three questions:

1. $g(x)$, which I think, is zero form on $G$, right?
2. What is $k$? By searching previous lectures given by Wu, I didn't find what it is here.
3. Why trace here? How to write that formulas down from the definition of **pull-back**?

Comment: Did you mean Lie group instead of Lee-Group manifold?

Comment: He said the Lie group can also be viewed as a manifold. Sorry I am not an math expert and do not kown the correct English word for it.

Comment: Can you say something about your background in Lie group?

Comment: I only know some basic definitions

Comment: Can you also provide the relevant lecture notes where this is introduced?

Comment: In the video https://www.koushare.com/video/videodetail/4579  24'14''      His lecture is in Chinese, but the lecture notes are in English and maybe sufficient for an expert to understand what he says. Please kindly have a look

Comment: For the benefit of whoever's interested in answering this question, I will add that in the lecture notes, the full sentence was "We have the pull-back $Tr\{[g^{-1}(x) d g(x)]^k\}$ on $M$ of $Tr\{[g^{-1}dg]^k\}$ (with wedge product understood) on $G$." Then the slide went on to explain that $g^{-1} dg$ is the Maurer-Cartan form, gave coordinate expressions for it and the pullback. I assume $k$ is the dimension of the Lie group $G$, and the notation $[-]^k$ is to note explicitly that you're taking the trace of a $k\times k$ matrix.

Comment: I was watching the video a bit. Professor Wu says around 19' "we have the **pull-back** $Tr\{[g^{-1}(x)dg(x)]^k\}$ on $M$ **of** $Tr\{[g^{-1}dg]^k\}$ (with wedge product understood) on $G$. Here $g^{-1}dg$ is the **Cartan-Maurer 1-form** on G of the form..." . @xian sun, I guess without giving a lot more background from that lecture there is no hope that someone will formulate an answer to your questions. Or maybe, the questions answer themselves ?

Comment: Also you might find [this post from Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625377/topological-meaning-of-the-integral-of-the-trace-of-cartan-maurer-forms-in-antho) relevant.